# How do I obtain the Fishcake?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

I've seen a few players who had the fishcake, and though I'm aware it is just a reskin of another food item, I still would like to have it. I checked the [Mann Co. Store](http://store.teamfortress.com/), but it's not available for purchase. Is my only option to trade for it, or are there other options?

Comment: What else is there to ask?

Comment: Context can make a question better. Too much context can make a question worse. And a question without context is not necessarily automatically bad.

Comment: @Sterno A question with no context shows an absolute lack of effort, and is completely and utterly worthy of downvotes for exactly that reason.  Yeah, the question is valid, and we're not closing it, but that doesn't mean the asker is absolved from demonstrating prior effort.

Comment: @fbueckert I fix my question, and you're still complaining? wow.

Comment: @fbueckert I'm not at my home computer at the moment so I can't boot up TF2 regardless. I guess some people just need something to complain about to get by. Too bad SE doesn't have a blocking feature.

Comment: @Scootaloo I've checked the [TF2 store](http://store.teamfortress.com/), and the item is not available there. I've edited your question to reflect that.

Comment: @fbueckert What have I done wrong now? I ask a simple question you complain about it, and I fix it. Then to make things worse everyone is having a wondering time trash talking about my question [on The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10868705#10868705). I really do want to ask/answer questions to the best of my ability, but rather than telling me _clearly_ what needs to be done you and the others just talk garbage behind my back.

Comment: @Scootaloo Not everyone is 'talking trash' about it on the Bridge.  I have been in and out all day, but I do recall a small group of users discussing this post earlier.  Why don't you join us in chat and see what's up?

Comment: @Scootaloo No one was trash talking your question.  Please take some time to read through that entire conversation and you'll see that we were discussing commenting etiquette.  This just happened to be the question that sparked that discussion.

Comment: @Scootaloo - We weren't trash talking your question.  Some of us were trying to point out that the comments left on this question were not as polite as they could be.  I personally have flagged most of the comments here, and I'm hoping a mod will come along and remove all of them.  Your question is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Fabricate Class Weapon blueprint can no longer create this item, but it is still craftable by using three Moustachium Bars and a Fish, which are promotional items earned in SpaceChem. SpaceChem can also give the items required to craft the SpaceChem Pin, another TF2 item.

Source: [TF2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fishcake)

Answer (score 0):

You can not obtain the fishcake as it was removed from the [Fabricate Class Weapon](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting#Tokens) [blueprint](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting).

I think if you have crafted it before it was removed then you would still be able to have this item.

You can try crafting it now, but not sure if it will work. you can see the ingredients [here](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Moustachium_Bar#As_a_crafting_ingredient), otherwise you can trade for it, I found the following on [team fortess 2 wiki](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fishcake#Bugs):

> If a player crafts an untradable Fishcake, clicking on the Fishcake item in their >backpack and pressing the Restore button will make it tradable.

hope this helps.

Comment: There are a bunch for trade on TF2WH for about 4 refined.